# symfony - sfDoctrineGuard - loading fixture data

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm currently using the `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` and `sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin` and when I reload data using `doctrine:data-load`

I get the following:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_db`.`sf_guard_user_profile`, CONSTRAINT`sf_guard_user_profile_user_id_sf_guard_user_id_1`FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES`sf_guard_user`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)`

This is really annoying as I can't seem to load any of the records that are in my fixtures.

I've copied the schema from the `sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin` and extended it a little bit:

```
sfGuardUserProfile:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: bigint(20)
      notnull: true
      default:
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      unique: false
      autoincrement: false
    email_new:
      type: string(255)
      unique: true
    firstname:
      type: string(255)
    lastname:
      type: string(255)
    city:
      type: varchar(255)
    validate_at:
      type: timestamp
    validate:
      type: string(33)
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      foreign: id
      local: user_id
      type: one
      onDelete: cascade
      foreignType: one
      foreignAlias: Profile
  indexes:
    validate:
      fields: [validate]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Load the fixtures in two or more batches - in such a way that parent data is loaded before loading child data, respecting the relationships between your tables. That's what the error is about.

Comment: But the loading of these fixtires have been generated from sf_guard_user. I have manually added these users in the admin and simply just `data-dump` and then tried to `data-load` in another database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had to add interger(11) to all of the tables in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. A bit hacky, but works now

Answer (score 1):

```
user_id:
  type: bigint(20)
```

ist not compatible to sfGuardUser

```
sfGuardUser:
  type: integer()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fixtures for sfGuardUserProfile you need to specify the sfGuardUser link as you have a foreign link to it that cannot be null

```
sfGuardUserProfile:
    bob_profile:
        sfGuardUser: bob  # Set the link
        firstname: bob
        # bobs_profile fixtures


sfGuardUser:
    bob:
       # bobs fixtures
```

Comment: These fixtures have been generated by me adding users via sfGuardUser in the admin so I'd hope they had the link!

Comment: So you did a data-dump to generate the fixtures?

Comment: Yeah I did. Anyways, looking in the `data.yml` i have things like: http://pastebin.com/UxKnHftm

Comment: @d.syph.3r  Still getting the same error, no matter what I do

Comment: Try removing the `default:` line from the sfGuardUserProfile user_id column

Comment: Removing that gives the same problem.

Comment: Ok, so I had to add `interger(11)` to all of the tables in `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin`. A bit hacky, but works now

Answer (score 0):

Check User's id type.
It has to be the same as sfGuardUserProfile user_id is: bigint(20)

Comment: Everything seems to be a bigint(20)